# Migrating PHP application to Python Webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have built an application with a front-end in PHP and back-end in Python at GAE. I'd like to have my complete application in Python, but I don't know how to start.

In the current PHP application I have setup an .htaccess file to rewrite every request (images, JavaScript etc excluded) to index.php. In the index.php I include the right page (php) file depending on the request path.

All the files needed per page are stored in a folder 'page', the names of the files match the lay-out of the url.

The code below is a start, but I think it gives an idea of where I'm heading toward.

```
import sys

def main(environ, start_response):
  dirs    = environ['PATH_INFO'].split('/')
  params  = {}
  action  = []

  for dir in dirs:
    if dir.count('='):
      param = dir.split('=')
      params[param[0]] = param[1]
    elif dir:
      action.append(dir)

   try:
     # get the right module (the code per page)
     page_module = 'pages.'+'.'.join(action)
     __import__(page_module)
     page = sys.modules[page_module]
     page_return_function = getattr(page, 'response')
   except:
     return 'PAGE NOT FOUND'

   html_return = ''
   html_return += page_return_function(environ, start_response)

   return html_return
```

The biggest problem I'm facing is I'd like to use 'webapp2' because it is embedded in GAE and it handles a lot of things (sessions etc).

Hope I have explained my problem clear, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: you'll do your routing via app.yaml. Start here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

Comment: My app.yaml is configured right, the request is routed to the right file.
`- url: /gfx
  static_dir: gfx
- url: /javascript
  static_dir: javascript
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
- url: /.*
  script: main.main`

Comment: your problem is not clear to me.

Comment: @Hendrik Please make an effort and deploy a python version of your app to for example myapp-pythonversion.appspot.com and then you can ask about any obvious problem you encounter. There is no straight way to convert a PHP app to python, you must start over.